# use of with clause in stored procedure

Tags: oracle11g

```
  create or replace procedure proc
  as
begin
declare
time_to_stay number(3):=90
   with date_partitions as
  (select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('
    select p.table_owner, 
   p.table_name, 
   p.high_value
    from   all_part_key_columns k, 
   all_tab_cols c, 
   all_tab_partitions p
   where  k.owner = c.owner
       and    k.column_name = c.column_name
       and    k.name = c.table_name
       and    k.owner = p.table_owner
       and    k.name = p.table_name
       and    (c.data_type = ''DATE'' or 
       c.data_type like ''TIMESTAMP%'')') 
        as xml
        from   dual)

     SELECT  x.*
        FROM    date_partitions p, 
       xmltable('/ROWSET/ROW'
       passing p.xml
       columns table_owner varchar2(30) 
                 path '/ROW/TABLE_OWNER',
                table_name varchar2(30) 
                path '/ROW/TABLE_NAME',
              high_value varchar2(30) 
                path '/ROW/HIGH_VALUE'
           ) x
                  where   to_date(substr(x.high_value,
                  instr(high_value, '''')+2,
                  19),
             'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') <= sysdate-time_to_stay
          end;
```

when I execute the code I procedure gets created. but does not work. When I try to compile the procedure I get the following error.
Error(7,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WITH" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset ...

If i execute this code with begin section, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've made a few typos:

namely:

your added

1. `DECLARE`. this is not needed for stored procedures.
2. your `time_to_stay` is needed before the begin block.
3. missing semi colon on the `time_to_stay`.
4. you have to have a for loop in there as this sql can return 2+ rows.

here's an example that just outputs the info to the buffer.

```
SQL>   create or replace procedure proc
  2    as
  3  time_to_stay number(3):=90;
  4  begin
  5     for r_tab in (with date_partitions as
  6                   (select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('
  7                      select p.table_owner,
  8                     p.table_name,
  9                     p.high_value
 10                      from   all_part_key_columns k,
 11                     all_tab_cols c,
 12                     all_tab_partitions p
 13                     where  k.owner = c.owner
 14                         and    k.column_name = c.column_name
 15                         and    k.name = c.table_name
 16                         and    k.owner = p.table_owner
 17                         and    k.name = p.table_name
 18                         and    (c.data_type = ''DATE'' or
 19                         c.data_type like ''TIMESTAMP%'')') as xml
 20                      from dual)
 21                  select x.*
 22                    from date_partitions p,
 23                         xmltable('/ROWSET/ROW' passing p.xml columns table_owner varchar2(30) path
 24                                   '/ROW/TABLE_OWNER', table_name varchar2(30) path '/ROW/TABLE_NAME',
 25                                   high_value varchar2(30) path '/ROW/HIGH_VALUE') x
 26                   where to_date(substr(x.high_value, instr(high_value, '''') + 2, 19),
 27                                 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') <= sysdate - time_to_stay)
 28    loop
 29      dbms_output.put_line(r_tab.table_owner||','||r_tab.table_name||','||r_tab.high_value);
 30    end loop;
 31  end;
 32  /

Procedure created.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a code formatter, mistake would jump straight to your eyes. On the line of `time_to_stay`, you omitted the final ;